# Can a Second Form change First Form's text?

Tags: c#, winforms

My form 2 is opened by form 1, like this:

```
Form2 fm2 = new Form2();

fm2.Show();
```

So now, can my form 2 change the text in the **TextBox** of the current form 1?

I have tried using the following:

```
Form1 fm1 = new Form1();

fm1.textBox_A.Text = "123";
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are creating a new instance of Form1 but you need to pass your existing instance to frm2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just found a way to do what I want.

for form2:

```
Form1 fm1;
public Form2(Form1 _Form1)
    {
        fm1 = _Form1;
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }
```

Then form1:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 fm2 = new Form2(this);
        fm2.Show();
    }

    public string ChangeText
    {
        get { return this.textBox_A.Text; }
        set
        {
            this.textBox_A.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

So now I can use the following in form 2 to change the Text in current Form1 by Form2:

```
fm1.ChangeText= "YAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
```

Answer (score 0):

in first step you should add new constructor in Form2

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form fm1;
public Form2(System.Windows.Forms.Form frm1)
{
    this.fm1 = frm1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

then just write this

```
fm1.textBox_A.Text = "123";
```